# Install Zend Framework 2 with console

Tags: php, ubuntu, console, zend-framework2

**EDIT:**
It exists now: ZFTool

I am trying to install *Zend Framework 2* on my *ubuntu* system. I have installed *ZF1.11.11* with `apt-get install zend-framework`, but I would like to install the latest *Zend Framework*, *ZF2*.

I am a newbie in both ZF and Ubuntu. So, was really easy for me to manage a little project with lines like:

```
zf create project
zf create model
zf create action
zf enable layout
```

So, if I install zend with some tools like *composer*, *pyrus* or even just extract *Zend* into `Skeleton Project`, the project should work, but I would really miss the console. Makes my life much easier.

Is there a way? Could someone give me some console commands having *zf*?

Comment: ZF2 currently does not have a CLI command tool like in ZF1.

Comment: Are you sure? Make it a response so I can match your answer after a bit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to install the framework via commandline is using GIT and Composer. Check out [this part of the official Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html) for installation guidelines.

And as mentioned by Jani, a CLI as in ZF1 is yet to be created. It will come sooner or later, but for now there is none.

Comment: *Doh*, that sucks. That's why I couldn't find anything about *zf2* console in the past days. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

manual installation:

1) Download Zip file .from site (http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest )
2) extracted it in /var/www/ directory 
3) set the suitable permission to the directory

```
$ sudo chmod -R 0755  /var/www/ZendFramework-1.11.12/
```

4) enable the Zend framework tool or the zf tool. zf is a command line tool to create project and perform others operation for zend application. To enable the zf tool, we have to create a symlink to the tool. Copy and run the command to your shell

```
$ ln -s /var/www/ZendFramework-1.11.1/bin/zf.sh  /usr/bin/zf
```

5) enable the Library path to the php.ini.

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php :/var/www/ZendFramework-1.11.12/library"
```

6) Restart the apache

7) $ zf create project   `/var/www/example`

Comment: Thank you, but i needed zftool for zf2. Zftool for zf2 wasn't quite ready back when i started this thread. Appreciate it!

Comment: I just came across this post on SO, the quotes around include_path are invalid.